# backup script to exclude some parent dir and include some child dir

Tags: backup

What I'm trying to do backup?

1. users home dir which include `Desktop`,`Documents`,`Pictures`, `thunderbird` which i need to backup of every user
2. all users are in `/home` partition with there respective user name
3. there are certain user AND files in `/home` which need to be exclude

What I've tried so far?

```
$ tar cvf home01 -T include /home
```

**NOTE:** T which says only take that which are mention in file but does not work

```
$ find . \( -name \*Desktop -o -name \*Documents\* -o -name \*Pictures\*  -o -name \.thunderbird\*   \)  |
  xargs  tar zcvf /opt/rnd/home-$(date +%d%m%y).tar.zip
```

**NOTE:** which takes backup of mention dir but it puts every users dir into one folder.

#### For example

```
$ ls -l /home

/home/user1/{Desktop,Documents,Pictures,.thunderbird}
/home/user2/{Desktop,Documents,Pictures,.thunderbird}
/home/user3/{Desktop,Documents,Pictures,.thunderbird}
/home/user4/{Desktop,Documents,Pictures,.thunderbird}
/home/user5/{Desktop,Documents,Pictures,.thunderbird}
```

From which I need to take only `user1`,`user2`,`user3` home dir backup and exclude `user4`,`user5`

Answer (score 2):

You're nearly there! This should do:

```
tar zcvf /opt/rnd/home-$(date +%d%m%y).tar.zip */{Desktop,Documents,Pictures,.thunderbird} --exclude=user4 --exclude=user5
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do it retaining your use of the `find` command:

```
$ find . \( -type d -path */Desktop -o -path */.thunderbird -o -path */Pictures \\) \! -path '*user[45]*' -prune | xargs  tar zcvf /opt/rnd/home-$(date +%d%m%y).tar.gz
```

Here's an easier version to look at:

```
$ find . \( -type d                                                   \
     -path */Desktop -o -path */.thunderbird -o -path */Pictures \)   \
     \! -path '*user[45]*' -prune                                     \
  | xargs  tar zcvf /opt/rnd/home-$(date +%d%m%y).tar.gz
```

This will find all the directories with the names in the first parens block `\( ... \)`. These are the directories:

- `*/Desktop`
- `*/thunderbird`
- `*/Pictures`

The 2nd part excludes any paths that match the pattern `*user[45]*`. These pare pruned out of the list. Finally the resulting list of directories to passed to tar.

#### Additional things to consider

The above is **NOT** bullet-proof. It will exclude paths that include the string `user4` or `user5` in them. Also some care should be given to making sure that whatever you construct as a command can deal with spaces in filenames.